# java simple if statement not evaluating properly

Tags: java

any idea why this doesnt work?  actual code below and picture of run time from debugger, if statement should set variable Testnumber =  1;  but when its evaluated it is = 0 ?????

```
private String Convert2Time(int Number){
    int  Hours, Minutes, HrsRemainder, MinRemainder, Seconds; String RetString, OneString, TwoString, ThreeString, HoursStr, MinStr, SecStr;
    byte Testnumber = 0;
    Hours = Number / 3600;
    HrsRemainder = Number % 3600;
    Minutes = HrsRemainder / 60;
    MinRemainder = HrsRemainder % 60;
    Seconds = MinRemainder / 1;

    HoursStr = Integer.toString(Hours);
    MinStr = Integer.toString(Minutes);
    SecStr = Integer.toString(Seconds);
    ThreeString = HoursStr + " Hrs " + MinStr + " Min " + SecStr + " Sec";
    TwoString = MinStr + " Min " + SecStr + " Sec";
    OneString = SecStr + " Sec";
    if (Hours < 0){
        Testnumber = 2;
    } else {
        if (Minutes < 0){
            Testnumber = 1;
        }
    }
    switch (Testnumber){
        case 2:
            RetString = ThreeString;
            break;
        case 1:
            RetString = TwoString;
            break;
        default:
            RetString = OneString;
    }
    return RetString;
}
```

[Code from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iVn0.jpg)

Comment: javascript !== java

Comment: click on Code from debugger:  with number = 61; I get Minutes =1 and Seconds = 1  so If statement should evaluate to Testnumber = 1;   but actually evaluates to Testnumer = 0?????

Comment: Please use lowerCaser, it would be more readable

Comment: You don't need the `HoursStr` intermediary variable. You can add `int` + `String` which becomes `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your method it seems that you wanted to convert number of seconds to readable time.

That main problem was the condition. Hours, Minutes, Seconds will always have valid grater or equal zero, they will not be negative. Because you are dividing a positive number.

So any condition like `Hours < 0`, `Seconds < 0` will never return true;
You need to invert them. Because only when there are any hours, minutes, seconds you wish to add correct chunk to your response.

```
private String Convert2Time(int Number) {
        int Hours, Minutes, HrsRemainder, MinRemainder, Seconds;
        Hours = Number / 3600;
        HrsRemainder = Number % 3600;
        Minutes = HrsRemainder / 60;
        Seconds = HrsRemainder % 60;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (Hours > 0) {
            result.append(Hours).append(" Hra ");
        } 
        if (Minutes > 0) {
            result.append(Minutes).append(" Min ");
        }

        result.append(Seconds).append( " Min ");

        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: YES !!!  Holy Brain Fart Batman,    I was thinking the less than symbol was the greater than symbol.    I  need a vacation!

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem please close the issue, or accept any answer. To keep stackOverflow clean. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your output, the `Hours < 0` and `Minutes < 0` both evaluate to `false`. There is no reason why it would set `TestNumber = 1;` or even `TestNumber = 2;`. It remains `0` from `byte Testnumber = 0;`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your complicating your code unnecessarily. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use existing Java classes to do the work for you:

```
int numInSeconds = 61;
int millis = numInSeconds * 1000;
Date time = new Date(millis);

int hours = time.getHours();
int mins = time.getMinutes();
int secs = time.getSeconds();

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
if (hours > 0) {
    builder.append(hours);
    builder.append(" hrs ");
}
// etc.
String displayTime = builder.toString(); // "1 mins 1 secs"
```

Comment: Yes thank you for the comment, that is part of the problem, I do not know of all the pre-built classes.  I will have to do more research

Comment: @jetro57070 Everyone's been there before!